# Lightweight long-running method cancel pattern for Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is there a lightweight pattern to cancel long running method, which replaces code like this:

```
public void longComputations() {
   ... first step...
   if ( cancelled ) {
      rollbackWork();
      return;
   }
   ... second step...
   if ( cancelled ) {
      rollbackWork();
      return;
   }
   ... third step...
   if ( cancelled ) {
      rollbackWork();
      return;
  }
}
```

I know that I can make a Task class, subdivide steps to task objects, make a queue and just do tasks step by steps in loop with cancelation checking, but I'm just wondering is there any simple code-structure pattern for such situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of such a mechanism. Since you have to track your work in order to be able to perform `rollbackWork()`, a well-designed object-oriented solution is your best choice anyway, if you want to further evolve this logic! Typically, such a scenario could be implemented using the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), which I still find pretty lightweight:

```
// Task or Command
public interface Command {
    void redo();
    void undo();
}
```

A scheduler or queue could then take care of executing such task / command implementations, and of rolling them back in order.

Comment: I will accept due to enough time period. But propably the real answer is "No, there is not a simple code structure for that". Your solution is a little bit heavyweight (as I said `subdivide steps to task objects`) for very small process, but I think that is a lot better practice that involving thread exteptions/thread interruption.

Answer (score 2):

How about this edit, not a pattern though? Exceptions are very cheap, so it should be fast.

```
public void caller(){
    try{
        longComputations();
    } catch (MeaningfulRuntimeException e){
        rollbackWork(e.getStep());
    }
}

public void longComputations() {
   ... first step...
   checkStatus(1);

   ... second step...
   checkStatus(2);

   ... third step...
   checkStatus(3);
}

public void checkStatus(int step){
    if ( cancelled ) {
        ... we may rollback here or throw an exception ...
        throw MeaningfulRuntimeException(step);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the steps call methods which throw `InterruptedException` then you can use [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29). You will still need to maintain enough state information to do the rollback properly.

If the steps cannot be interrupted this way, you should **not** consider relying on the deprecated [`Thread.stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) mechanism since it is inherently unsafe.

It seems that either way it makes sense to do exactly what you described: encapsulate this workflow logic in a class independent of the computation steps. It should support cancellation and/or interruption and accept a bunch of tasks to be executed. Note that the tasks to be fed into the workflow should provide at least two methods: one to perform the computation and one to roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the java.util.concurrent package. You need to wrap your working steps as Callables (or Runnables).

```
public class InterruptibleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) { try {
        final ExecutorService queue = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        queue.submit(new Callable<Void>() { @Override public Void call() { busyWait(1000); return null; } });
        queue.submit(new Callable<Void>() { @Override public Void call() { busyWait(1000); return null; } });
        queue.submit(new Callable<Void>() { @Override public Void call() { busyWait(1000); return null; } });
        final AtomicBoolean cancelled = new AtomicBoolean();
        new Thread() { @Override public void run() {
                try { Thread.sleep(1500); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                queue.shutdownNow();
                cancelled.set(true);
            }
        }.run();
        if (cancelled.get()) { rollback(); }
        queue.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(System.err); } }

    public synchronized static void busyWait(int millis) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        long until = System.currentTimeMillis() + millis;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < until) { }
        System.out.println("Stopped");
    }
    public synchronized static void rollback() {
        System.out.println("Rollback!");
    }
}
```

Note that shutdownNow() might call interrupt() on the currently executing work thread. You will probably also need to synchronize your rollback() because shutdownNow() returns before non-interruptible code finishes execution.